# Adobe CS5.1; I want the measure tool as the default; when I use Ctrl-I, the measure (ruler) tool appears... is this sort of thing possible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, measurement

I scan many slides, transparencies, and negatives. I need to straighten them often. I would like the ruler/measurement tool under CTRL-I to remain as the default with eveery start of Photoshop. Is it possible to make it the default instead of the eyedropper tool?
Perhaps a shortcut key of its own might work as well... where one keystroke will bring it to the top... will it stay there? hmmm. . .
I've just given myself an idea...  (LOL)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign shortcuts and have the ruler set to pop-up when you hit a key. Go Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Select `Shortcuts for: Tools`

PS should remember your tool you used last in the set and keep that at top, make sure you close properly for PS to "remember"